# What is the probability of an outcome in general, if you know its respective probabilities in a bunch of other situations?

Tags: probability, statistics

Say there are choices A, B, C, D, and E, and I want to know the probability of A being selected, but I only know the probability of A when compared to only 2 other choices.

For example,
I know for a fact that given the choice between A, B, C : I have a P(A) = .2

A, B, D : P(A) = .3

A, B, E : P(A) = .8

A, C, D : P(A) = .6

A, C, E : P(A) = .43

A, D, E : P(A) = .61

Is there a way for me to find out the probability that A will chosen? In the example I listed all the possible combinations, but what if I was missing one, let's say I didn't have the (A,D,E) variant? How would that effect the probabilities? What if I had the probabilities for all the other 3 choice combinations that don't include A like (B,C,D), (B,C,E)... etc? Would those help me?

For the record, all the numbers I gave are made up, and so is this problem. I'm simply very curious.

Comment: I think the linear system of equations is contradictory: There is no model that fits this data.

Answer (score 1):

What you know in the first case is the probability of $A$ given $ A \cup B \cup D $. From Bayes' theorem you have
$$ P(A | A\cup B\cup C) = \frac{P(A)P(A\cup B\cup C | A)}{P(A\cup B\cup C)} $$
Since your choices are distinct this can be written as
$$  P(A | A\cup B\cup C) = \frac{P(A)}{P(A)+P(B)+P(C)} $$
or using the actual numbers
$$ 0.3 = \frac{P(A)}{P(A)+P(B)+P(C)} \Rightarrow $$
$$ P(A) = 0.3P(A) + 0.3P(B) + 0.3P(C) \Rightarrow $$
$$ 0.7P(A) - 0.3P(B) - 0.3P(C) = 0. $$
If you have four of these kind of relations, together with $ P(A) + \dots + P(E) = 1$, you have a 5x5 linear system of equations, if the numbers are good, you can solve it and find the probabilities.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Where did you get the 0.7, -0.3 and -0.3? You said you used my numbers to get those right?

Comment: A, B, D : P(A) = .3. So the left hand side equals 0.3. I will edit my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying. But I don't think the relationships I listed can be represented as a Union like that. I suppose it's my fault for not making it clear, but the choices are mutually exclusive. Like if A, B, and D are basketball, football, and baseball, then P(A) = 0.2 means that there is a 20% chance someone selects to play basketball.

Comment: I actually use the fact that they are mutually exclusive when replacing $ P(A\cup B \cup C ) $ with $ P(A) + P(B) + P(C) $.

Comment: Letting $a=P[A]$, $b=P[B]$, and so on, you get equations like $a=(0.3)(a+b+d)$, $a=(0.8)(a+b+e)$ and so on, with 6 equations (including $a+b+c+d+e=1$) and 5 unknowns.  I believe the system has no solution (so, the numbers are not good).

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking so too. Which means would have to try to do inference some other way